# How to execute a line of code saved as a variable VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form called Frm_Dairy and a form called Frm_Bakery

I have a field in each of them that holds a value.  The names of the fields in each form are the same but for the beginning of the name of the field which is ether Dairy or Bakery.

Example:
Frm_Dairy.Dairy_Sales
or
Frm_Bakery.Bakery_Sales

I want to execute this code:
M_Sales = Frm_Dairy.Dairy_Sales

This is easy enough but what if I want the program to 1st figure out what form is active?

M_Form = "Dairy" 'in this case

So if M_Form = "Dairy" the code would be:
M_Code = "M_Sales = Frm_" & M_Form & "." & M_Form & "_Sales"

Now how do I execute the M_Code variable to get the data stored into M_Sales

I hope I have asked this question with enough detail and thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you have 2 forms? What table(s) are forms bound to? What table are you saving data into?

Answer (score 1):

To determine if a particular form is open, consider:

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms("Dairy").IsLoaded Then
...
ElseIf CurrentProject.AllForms("Bakery").IsLoaded Then
...
End If
```

You describe need to reference fields, probably really need to reference controls.

Several ways to dynamically construct form and control references. One is to use the ActiveForm property, assuming the form you want to address has focus.

`Debug.Print Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(Screen.ActiveForm.Name & "_Sales")`

Another would be to pass the form name as string argument of procedure.

`Debug.Print Forms(strForm).Controls(strForm & "_Sales")`

Would be simpler if controls do not have form name prefix.

Comment: Thanks June7.  This is close to what I have done as a work around.  My problem is not in determining what form is active. I'm trying to make one function that will execute 100 lines of code based on the department that is active.  The lines of code are identical except each line of code that references a field begins with the department that is active.

Comment: I should also mention that there are 12 different departments and each department has 12 fields.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: So you have 12 identical forms? I still wonder why not one form.

Comment: If you have 12 identical tables, should probably be 1 table with another field for the department ID.